# Implementing clone on a LinkedList

Tags: java, cloning, cloneable

I am trying to implement a `clone()` method on a `DoubleLinkedList`. Now, the problem is that implementing it by "the convention" is a lot more troublesome than just creating a new `DoubleLinkedList` and filling it with all the elements of my current DoubleLinkedList.

Is there any inconvenient I am not seeing when doing that?

Here is my current approach:

```
@Override
public DoubleLinkedList<T> clone() {
    DoubleLinkedList<T> dll = new DoubleLinkedList<T>();

    for (T element : dll) {
        dll.add(element);
    }

    return dll;
}
```

Here is what it would be by the convention:

```
@Override
public DoubleLinkedList<T> clone() {
    try {
        DoubleLinkedList<T> dll = (DoubleLinkedList<T>)super.clone();
        //kinda complex code to copy elements
        return dll;
    } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
        throw new InternalError(e.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you correctly point out, the convention is to always call `super.clone()` in the beginning of an implementation of `clone()`. From the [API docs on `Object#clone()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29):

> By convention, the returned object should be obtained by calling super.clone. If a class and all of its superclasses (except Object) obey this convention, it will be the case that x.clone().getClass() == x.getClass().

Your first attempt (without using `super.clone()`) has the following problem:

Suppose I have

```
class IntDoubleLinkedList extends DoubleLinkedList<Integer> implements Cloneable
```

(and that `IntDoubleLinkedList` does not bother to override `clone()`) and I run the following code:

```
IntDoubleLinkedList idll = new IntDoubleLinkedList();
IntDoubleLinkedList idll2 = (IntDoubleLinkedList) idll.clone();
```

What will happen? The clone method of *your* `DoubleLinkedList` will be executed, which, if it doesn't go through super.clone(), returns an instance of `DoubleLinkedList` which in turn can not be casted to an `IntDoubleLinkedList`. **A `ClassCastException` will be thrown!**

So how does `super.clone()` solve this issue? Well, if everybody stick to the convention of calling `super.clone()` in an overriden clone method, `Object.clone()` will eventually be called, and this implementation will create an instance of a proper type (`IntDoubleLinkedList` in this case)!

Comment: Note that this convention only applies/matters if the class isn't final. If DoubleLinkedList is final, then you know that the ultimate type and may clone by whatever mechanism suits (e.g. see Effective Java 2nd Ed, Item 7: "If the class is
final, clone can even return an object created by a constructor.")

Comment: That's a good point. Going through super.clone() is merely a favor to whoever extends our class, and not a favor to "ourself". Disallowing subclassing of a list implementation seems strange though.

Comment: Item 17, "Design and document for inheritance or else prohibit it" :) And 'designing and documenting for inheritance' is a lot more difficult than people think, and leads to subtle bugs. There's an argument that the default should be to make classes final, and only remove it after careful consideration.... but yes, I see your point. I was just playing devil's advocate.

Answer (score 1):

As others have explained, if you're going to override `clone` you should obey its contract.

If you like the way you currently have it, just make `DoubleLinkedList` not `Cloneable` and turn your implementation into a copy constructor or static factory method. A static factory method has the added benefit of providing a bit of type inferencing for generic type arguments, too.

P.S. [`LinkedList`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) *is* a doubly-linked list.

Comment: Your answer sounds a bit contradictory. Letting it work like a copy-constructor does not emphasize that one should go through the `super.clone` which is suggested in the contract of clone: By convention, the returned object should be obtained by calling super.clone.

Comment: I'm telling @devoured elysium to just forget about `clone` and write it as a copy constructor or static factory method instead, since (s)he already has an implementation in mind that is perfectly acceptable in one of those.

I'll update my answer to (I hope) be more clear.

Comment: +1 for your P.S., I hope OP is doing this as a learning exercise and not because they think they HAVE to because LinkedList is only singly-linked. :S

Answer (score 0):

If you do it by creating a new list and adding all the elements from the source, if you then do something like:

```
DoubleLinkedList<Foo> l1 = new DoubleLinkedList<Foo>();
l1.add (new Foo(params));
DoubleLinkedList<Foo> l2 = l1.clone();
Foo foo = l2.get(0);
foo.setProperty("new Value");
```

foo.property will be "new value" in both lists (the same the other way around; if you change it in l1, changes will appear in l2). The correct way would be to actually clone every element and the add the clone to ensure the lists are independent. Take note that this only happens if you change properties of the elements, not if you add, move, delete them from the list.

Edit: just realized that since it's a linked list, the next/previous elements are properties of the element, so even adding, deleting, will affect both list.

Comment: Nothing wrong with letting clone implement a shallow copy. It is in fact the way `LinkedList` in the Java API does it!

Comment: I didn't say it was wrong; he asked if there are any inconvenients, and I pointed this out, since some people might consider this to be one (some other people might not), so he can decide for himself it it's ok that it does that.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the "convention" is to call `super.clone()` is to ensure the ultimate type of the cloned object matches the object that is being cloned. For example if you instantiate your own new `DoubleLinkedList` in the `clone()` method, well that's nice for now, but later if a subclass fails to override `clone()` it will end up returning a clone that is a `DoubleLinkedList` instead of its own class. (It'll also fail to clone its additional fields, if any, probably! so there are larger issues.)

In that sense, the conventional method is preferred, and it is indeed clunky.

Both implementations, however, have a similar problem: you're not deep-copying the data structures. The clone is only a shallow cop. This is probably not what the caller expects. You would need to go through and replace each value in the `DoubleLinkedList` with a clone of the value, and likewise for other non-primitive fields.

In that sense, the conventional method is going to give the wrong result here! You need a third way. Your first method probably just about works, except that you need to add `element.clone()` for example.

Comment: I would **expect a shallow copy** since that is what the API list implementations provide (such as LinkedList: "Returns a shallow copy of this LinkedList. (The elements themselves are not cloned.)")

Comment: The first method (not calling super.clone()) does not follow the convention. See the docs on Object#clone() and my answer.

Comment: See my comment to aioobe about the convention -- it does not need to be followed if the class is final and cannot be subclassed.